# Select rows that match all selected rows from a join table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of entries and a table of categories with a join table linking the two, what I want to do is select all the entries that match a specific set of categories.

eg. All entries that have category A AND category B

entries

```
entry_id | title
------------------
1        | Entry 1
2        | Entry 2
3        | Entry 3
```

categories

```
category_id | name
------------------
1           | A
2           | B
3           | C
```

entry_categories

```
entry_id | category_id
-----------------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 1
2        | 2
2        | 3
3        | 1
3        | 3
```

If I do this I get all 3 entries because they each match at least one of the categories, but what I really want is Entry 1 and Entry 2 but not Entry 3.

```
SELECT *
FROM entry_categories AS ec
INNER JOIN entries AS e ON ec.entry_id = e.entry_id
WHERE ec.category_id IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY e.entry_id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `HAVING COUNT(ec.Categor_id) = 2` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM entry_categories AS ec
INNER JOIN entries AS e ON ec.entry_id = e.entry_id
WHERE ec.category_id IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY e.entry_id
HAVING COUNT(ec.Category_id) = 2
```

Comment: Might want to fix the spelling and case of that (`COUNT(ec.Categor_id)` to `COUNT(ec.category_id)`).

Comment: @MichaelRushton - Sorry, Fixed now. Thanks